How can I export blend file into glb format for DeepAR?
All the textures added to the object/mesh erases auto after exporting it as glb format for DeepAR where it should remain shame even after the deepar virtual try-on.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Not all Blender material nodes can export to glTF / GLB.  Try arranging them in patterns that are explained in the glTF exporter documentation in the Blender Manual here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html
